# Cisco ASA OCSP configuration

Tags: cisco-asa

Can anyone help me understand how to configure OCSP on my Cisco ASA?

I have AnyConnect Over IKEv2 to ASA with AAA and Certificate Authentication. As RootCA server I have OpenSSL. Now I want to implement OCSP, but instructions are little confusing.

So, as I understand when configuring OCSP server on OpenSSL RootCA i generate **OCSP signing certificate**, that is signed by OpenSSL Root certificate. While generating that certificate I have to include an **ocsp-no-check** extension which indicates that this certificate does not need revocation status checking.

That **OCSP signing certificate** I must import on ASA under his own trustpoint. What does it mean: "To configure a trustpoint to validate a self-signed OCSP responder certificate, you import the self-signed responder certificate into its own trustpoint as a trusted CA certificate"? **OCSP signing certificate**, is signed by OpenSSL Root certificate, it is not self-signed? Also, do I need **#revocation-check none** under OCSR trustpoint?

Then documentation say: "Then you configure the match certificate command in the client certificate validating trustpoint to use the trustpoint that includes the self-signed OCSP responder certificate to validate the responder certificate." What trustpoint is **client certificate validating trustpoint**? Is that Root certificate of CA server on my ASA? How should that match certificate command look like?

Something like:

```
#crypto ca certificate map MAP 10
   #subject-name co user
#crypto ca trustpoint ROOTCA
   #match certificate MAP override ocsp trustpoint OCSP 10 url http://ip_address_of_my_CA/OCSP_server/ocsp
```

Does **#revocation-check ocsp** command then goes under ROOTCA trustpoint?

Because, documentation say: "VPN configuration requires successful authorization (that is, a valid certificate)",

Do i need **#authorization-required** command under tunnel-group general-attributes?

Do I need **#aaa authorization LOCAL** command?